# Selecting TimeStamp difference with INNER JOIN

Tags: php, mysql

I want to select the fields that satisfy a timestamp difference condition between the "datetime" columns in two tables. I use the INNER JOIN procedure. In the ON condition I feel neccessary to convert the "datetime" data in timestamp using strtotime function as follows:

```
$Seuil = 120;
$stm = $dbco->prepare
("SELECT picbruit.Id_B, survols.Id_S 
FROM picbruit
INNER JOIN survols
ON (strtotime(survols.date_S) - strtotime(picbruit.date_B)) < :sl");
$stm->execute([':sl'=>$Seuil]);
```

I received the following message (note that valpic is the name of the database):
Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1305 FUNCTION valpic.strtotime does not exist in C:\wamp64\www\formationwamp\Correle_PS.php on line 24

What would be the appropriate syntax to circumvent this issue?

Comment: There is nothing called `strtotime` in `MySQL`. You may need to use `date_format` https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html

Comment: strtotime is a PHP function. Go check https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html

Comment: Thanks. My fault! I tried to use "DATEDIFF (Survols.date_S, Picbruit.date_B) < $Seuil"  but it was unseccessfull. Sincerely I am  now wondering if using JOIN is the proper approach to address my partcular objective. Any clue?

Comment: I am about to give up! One question: is it possible to use an inequality condition in the ON statement of a JOIN? I only find examples with equality conditions. My problem is one more level of difficulty since I need to compare two DATETIME information in the database.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution by defining the columns date_S ans date_B as TIMESTAMP instead of DATETIME. The comparison under the ON statement is therefore straightforward. Proof:

```
$pdo->query("CREATE TABLE Picbruit (Id_B INT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,date_B TIMESTAMP)");
$pdo->query("CREATE TABLE Survols (Id_S INT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,date_S TIMESTAMP)");
$pdo->query("INSERT INTO `Picbruit`(`date_B`) VALUES ('2022-08-31 08:53:47')");
$pdo->query("INSERT INTO `Picbruit`(`date_B`) VALUES ('2022-07-31 07:53:47')");
$pdo->query("INSERT INTO `Picbruit`(`date_B`) VALUES ('2022-07-31 07:53:47')");
$pdo->query("INSERT INTO `Survols`(`date_S`) VALUES ('2022-08-31 08:53:47')");
$pdo->query("INSERT INTO `Survols`(`date_S`) VALUES ('2022-07-30 08:53:47')");
$pdo->query("INSERT INTO `Survols` (`date_S`) VALUES ('2022-08-31 08:53:47')");
$Seuil = 60;
$stm = $pdo->prepare
("SELECT Picbruit.Id_B , Survols.Id_S FROM Picbruit
  INNER JOIN Survols
  ON ABS(Survols.date_S - Picbruit.date_B) < $Seuil") ;
 $stm->execute([]);
 $result=$stm->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)
print_r ($result);
```